# Transfers between locations bar graph SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Given that I have a table with the current information of inter transfers between locations:

```
FromLoc         ToLoc           qty
NYC             LA              1842
NYC             CALI            752
LA              CALI            175
LA              NYC             5
CALI            NYC             2
CALI            LA              2691
```

I would like to display a bar graph that looks something like this: 
http://www.act.org/collegechoice/12/i/p3/college-trans-8.png

So the X-axis would display 'NYC', 'LA', 'CALI'
and NYC would show how many transfers came in to the warehouse and how many transfers went out of the warehouse and etc. I've tried playing around with this in the report builder but nothing seems to be working. Is there a way I can do this. How would this query look like.

Would it also be possible to have a graph for example NYC as a category in the x-axis and have NYC out to LA, CALI (for out) and so forth. Then I can probably do a similar graph but just for NYC In to LA, CALI.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

CTE is getting distinct locations from both FromLoc and ToLoc column values

We are doing group by on all locations and doing CASE based aggregation to find Out of Wharehouse and In to Warehouse values

```
; with CTE
as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT FromLoc as Location from Table1
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT ToLoc as Location from Table1
)
SELECT Location , SUM( CASE WHEN T1.FromLoc = Location THEN T1.qty END) as 'Out of Warehouse',
                  SUM(CASE WHEN T1.ToLoc = Location THEN T1.qty END) as 'In to Warehouse'
FROM CTE
JOIN Table1 T1
on CTE.Location = T1.FromLoc
OR CTE.Location = T1.ToLoc
GROUP BY CTE.Location
```

In your case the output will look like

```
Location    Out of Warehouse    In to Warehouse
CALI              2693             927
LA                180              4533
NYC               2594             7
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't quiet work the way I need it to work. For example If its just from NYC to LA (that I want to know about), then this table displays.

Comment: @user2684009, you can limit it by where clause

Comment: Sorry I meant...what I wanted to be able to track Which location sent the most Items to which location and Which location received the most items from which location. Can that be graphically depicted?